# Amazon SESにおいてバウンスメールを解除し、メール送信できるようにしたいです。（今後発生しうるメールアドレスにも対応したい）

Tags: amazon-ses

Amazon SESを用いてRailsアプリケーションから一斉メール配信をしていますが、
週に5,6件のバウンス(メール不達)が発生しており、バウンスの検知はできております。

現状ではGmailアカウントから対象のバウンスメールに個別送信すると問題なく送信できるため、これまではそのような手動オペレーションをしておりました。

ただ、毎度手動でおこなうのは大変なため、SESからバウンスメールを解除し、送信できるようにしたいです。

以下のケースにおいて、対策を打ちたいと思っております。

1. 過去バウンスメールに引っかかったメールアドレス
2. 今後バウンスメールに引っかかった場合のメールアドレス

---

**質問1**
こういったことは可能でしょうか？

**質問2**
また、過去のバウンスメールに引っかかったメールアドレスの傾向を把握したいと思っており、バウンスメール一覧のようなものをAWSのCLIを使って取得できないかと思い、AWSのドキュメントを漁ってますが、見当たりません。バウンスメール一覧を取得することは可能でしょうか？

**質問3**
webアプリケーション側のメールのログに `status=bounced` と共に、次のようなドメインが含まれていたため、Outlookが起因する可能性が高いのでしょうか？
`xxxx.mail.protection.outlook.com`

以上宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: より広く回答を募るため、こちらにも投稿しております。https://teratail.com/questions/96054

Comment: 「バウンスの検知」はどのように行ってますか？

Answer (score 1):

(質問1)
バウンスとなった理由によりけりだと思いますが、
ハードバウンス（宛先不明、メールアドレス間違い、拒否されてるなど）の場合は、原因を取り除くことは難しいので、二度と送信しないのが良いと思います。
ソフトバウンスの場合は、一定期間時間を空けて再送信するとうまくいくこともあります。
Gmailで送信できるなら、バウンス通知をトリガーに ソフトバウンスの場合は Gmailで送信するプログラムを作れば自動化できる・・・ような気がします。

(質問2)
過去の分は取り出せません。
今後のバウンス通知のデータを貯めるしかないと思います。

(質問3)
バウンス通知の bounceType bounceSubType bouncedRecipients 辺りリをご覧いただくと何か理由が書いているかもしれません。
ご 参考[Amazon SES の Amazon SNS 通知のコンテンツ - Amazon Simple Email Service](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/notification-contents.html)

Answer (score 0):

大体のことは[SESの開発者ガイド](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/ses/latest/dg/Welcome.html)に記載されています。

「バウンスメール」という用語についておそらく一般的な用法とはことなる意味で使われているようで、何がしたいのかについては理解できませんでした。

用語は正しく使う、自信がないのであれば説明を付記されるのがよいと思います。

SESは標準では統計情報ぐらいしか取得できなかったはずです。ログの取得についても開発者ガイドの
[Amazon SES 送信アクティビティのモニタリング](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/ses/latest/dg/monitor-sending-activity.html)

に記載されていますのでこれを読みましょう。

xxxx.mail.protection.outlook.comはMSのメールサービスのゲートウェイです。個人向けOutlookやMicrosoft 365などです。ここでbounceされていてGmailから送ると届く、ということは、spam扱いされているか、ドメインの設定が不適切か、その両方です。もしカスタムドメインを使用しているのであればまず後者が疑われます。SMTPのセッションでは割と親切に詳細が記載されているはずなので、ログを取得するようにして確認してください。

SES(や同種のメール配送のサービス)は簡単なように見えて実は自前でSMTPを運用するより難易度が高いです(結局自前で運用するぐらいの知識はいる+SESの知識もいる)。適切に運用できないと割と簡単にサスペンドされます。そうすると全くメール送信ができなくなることになります。SES(など)が必須であるほど大量のメールを配送する必要があるのであれば、十分な準備が必要です。さもなくば、自前で運用する(信頼性は下がるが、よっぽどのことがなければ全部が止まることはない)ことも検討した方がよいかと。